# Line break in a property of JS in Lightning accordion

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, object, text

Is it possible create a line break in a property of a JavaScript object?

Like this:

```
const test= { name: account.Section__r.Name,
              label:  account.Section__r.Name + '\n' + account.Comments__c};

//account.Section__r.Name --> This is the test.
//account.Comments__c --> Line break here.
```

I put the '\n' element but in UI does not apply the line break. The result is this:

[image]

And I want this:

[image]

NOTE: Property is used in lightning-accordion-section label, as:

```
<lightning-accordion-section label={test.label}>
```

Comment: You can't unless it is `lightning-formatted-text` or `lightning-formatted-rich-text`. So, try to use one of them.

Comment: It really depends on what you have in your HTML template. Could you please add more details and the relevant part of the HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a line break using `'\n'` you have to use [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property with one of the following values

- `pre`: Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.
- `pre-wrap`: Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
- `pre-line`: Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line.

Since in the JS class you have something like `test = { name: 'bob', label: 'Hello\nWorld' };`, there are several way you could achieve that:

Via [Formatted Text component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-text/documentation). It converts the `\r` and `\n` characters into `<br />` tags.

```html
<div class="slds-var-p-bottom_small slds-border_bottom slds-var-m-bottom_small">
    <lightning-formatted-text value={test.label}></lightning-formatted-text>
</div>
```

Via tag [PRE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre), which represents preformatted text.

```html
<div class="slds-border_bottom slds-var-m-bottom_small">
    <pre>{test.label}</pre>
</div>
```

Via SLDS class Line Clamp

```html
<div class="slds-var-p-bottom_small slds-border_bottom slds-var-m-bottom_small">
    <div class="slds-line-clamp">{test.label}</div>
</div>
```

Via custom CSS: define a CSS class `.line-break { white-space: pre; }`

```html
<div class="slds-var-p-bottom_small slds-border_bottom slds-var-m-bottom_small">
    <div class="line-break">{test.label}</div>
</div>
```

You could also pass text formatted by HTML tags, such as `<br>`, to a [Formatted Rich Text component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation), so you would need to change the value in the JS `test = { name: 'bob', label: 'Hello<br/>World' };`

```html
<div class="slds-var-p-bottom_small slds-border_bottom slds-var-m-bottom_small">
        <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={test.label}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
</div>
```

You can try those examples [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/WnrDxaeiVbCttwo42CN4/src/app.css?p=stories)

Comment: Your comment is so helpful, but problem is that I want to put this in an accordion-section label. So, property is used like ```<lightning-accordion-section label={test.label}>```

Comment: @CPS due to shadow dom you cannot change its behavior, but you can build your own accordion component starting from the [blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/) and provide the needed style to the section label.